# redirect all website to other

Tags: windows

patch -  C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

How can I redirect all websites to other website?  
example for one:

```
 62.85.117.104 delfi.lv
```

i need for all websites..

```
62.85.117.104 *
```

(not work)

Comment: I suspect you don't actually want to screw with DNS like that, but actually want to setup a proxy, or some sort of authentication. There's probably a **much** better way to accomplish your goal, if you tell us what that goal is.

Answer (score 3):

You can't wildcard entries in the `hosts` file.

You would have to run your own DNS server that returned `62.85.117.104` for every query, then configure the network settings to use that server.